# Cloning nodes and performance, geometry, and performance; IOS Scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm writing a app using Scenekit where the client wishes to push the limits of animation in IOS. This particular app has requirements where I"m pushing out to the screen over 1,500 redraws. Even with this many redraws, I've locked down the FPS to 60, which is great, but when I add all elements the client wants, the redraws are pushed to 7,500 redraws (and yes, this isn't a mistake or a joke, this is the redraw number even though it's almost 50-80 times more than most redraw times I've seen with scenekit). At this level of redrawing, the screen contains 1.7 million vertices, and around 800k polygons. This is a a lot of stuff, and it's really too much stuff for this app to be useful to anyone because now my FPS drops to 15-30FPS which is expected from drawing over 3K geometry elements on screen. What I've done so far:

1. I clone all nodes, cloning allows me to push the limits of Scenekit. I was able to fit on screen over 1.5k constant CAAnimations with over 1.8K unique geometries placed in different locations across the screen.
2. I've forced all windows, views, and screens in app to be opaque by looping through all windows and setting their opaque property to yes.

Question is this, I can deal with the performance issues, but I'm having a problem with the node cloning. Well, the node cloning works, but the problem is that each geometry that is pushed to the screen must have a different size and it seems like there is no way to change the geometry of each separate clone. I know that I can change the geometry of a "copied" node (SCNNode *node = [masterNode copy];), and I know I can change the materials property of a cloned node, but is there a way to change the geometry of the cloned node? Apple doesn't give any insight about the geometry being changed, but they do talk about changing the materials. Am I to assume that I can't change the size of the geometry of the clone? I can change the transform, pivot, rotation, animation, position, etc, of the clone, but the size of the geometry won't change. For my purposes, I just need the "height" variable of a cylinder to be changeable, I have everything else in good order, AND, there's no other way to push over 2k redraws to a screen without node cloning, I've tried it without cloning and FPS drops to less than 10 with just 300 redraws when declaring each geometry and node with geometry as it's own unique variable.

Lastly, given this same scenario, how much of a performance increase should I expect by moving from Scenekit to Metal. I'm not worried about the math, the level of detail, the time consuming operations of setting up the rendering pipeline or whatever else might come my way, I'm merely trying to find the BEST solution for my problem here, and I've not used Metal yet because I'm not sure I'd get different results given how many polygons, vertices, and redraws are required. Thanks.

Comment: Redraws?  I'm don't understand.  Do you mean **draw calls** (per frame)?

Comment: Also, _“by moving from Scenekit to Metal”_ doesn't make a whole lot of sense— _SceneKit uses both OpenGL ES and Metal, allowing you switch which it's currently using with by initializing your `SCNView` with your desired `.preferredRenderingAPI` option. When in Metal-mode, SceneKit can even auto-convert (some) of your shader modifiers from ESSL to Metal Shader Language. So I'm not sure here if you want SceneKit to use Metal _(easy)_ or you want to eschew the high-level API of SceneKit and go straight OpenGL/Metal driver calls _(involved; difficult w/o a firm understanding of the API)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to change the geometry of the cloned node

I believe you can change the baked geometry itself, but not the parametric one (not the SCNCylinder). So you can (to change the height):

- Scale the node
- Change the Transformation Matrix (so scaling too, just a different way to)
- Add a Geometry Shader modifier that moves the points up/down on the axis you want

Changing the actual geometry kind of defeats the whole purpose of cloning, so I don't think there is a way around that.

> Lastly, given this same scenario, how much of a performance increase should I expect by moving from Scenekit to Metal.

A lot. Around 30% from what I've seen, but again it will depend on your setup. Metal comes with iOS 9, and you won't have to do anything to get it for your scene, so just update one of your devices and try it there, to see if it helps!

Out of curiosity: why do you need so much cylinders? Could you not cheat the way they are rendered?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The purpose of the cylinders is to show "connections" between people in 3D on the iphone screen. I don't know of any cheats to make this simpler, but I wish I did. I'm sort of new at this Scenekit stuff, but I now how to inject shaders, use plists for techniques, and more. Originally, I used primitive geometry lines instead of cylinders, but I don't know how to resize the lines since scenekit doesn't expose a variable to adjust primitive geometries. If you have any other suggestions, then please let me know, I can handle the maths, I'm just sort of new at the details.

Comment: Also, I can post another question here on Stack exchange if that would be better. I've not had to use stack for anything until now, so I'm new to posting here as well even though I've been an IOS dev for a few years. I want to make sure you get rewarded or whatever for answering any more questions.

Comment: You can ask a new question, that way you might get more answers than just mine as people may not look here. Don't forget to add details on what the final result should look like!

Comment: Just to underscore the most salient part of this answer: the `scale` property of nodes is a vector, so you can scale the y axis of your cylinders to change their height while leaving their circular cross section unchanged. Scale is a transformation applied during rendering, so you can thus make sure that all 1000+ cylinders all share the same geometry and not suffer a performance hit for uploading a zillion vertex buffers to the GPU.

Comment: That's perfect, Rickster, I was going to post yesterday this is the most important part for s

Comment: cenekit performance when using a ton of geometry. While messing around with GLKQuanternions and playing around with the individual ".m'X'" values of SCNMatrix4 matrices, I've discovered that Scenekit gives us developers a ton of control over what we can do. Apple docs only give a small snippet overview of everything we can do. Thanks again, Moustach, and thank you, Rickster. Little tidbits of information like this are not as small as they seem, it's this "node cloning/scaling" info that can make or break a graphics intensive app.